# Error when viewing node site uploaded with Heroku. Works fine when ran locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm currently trying to upload my site to Heroku and it uploads fine, but get an application error when trying to visit the site. Also when running the site locally with heroku or with node it works fine no problems. This is my Heroku logs.

```
2018-03-14T00:40:58.059502+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=kyleshrote.herokuapp.com 
request_id=0b3db092-64b3-412e-8f3d-7626e5805760 fwd="199.87.224.132" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-03-14T00:41:00.847606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=kyleshrote.herokuapp.com 
request_id=11ea8eb7-8927-40c0-8830-3927443e57d6 fwd="199.87.224.132" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-03-14T01:32:56.825817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `node server.js`
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882839+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:540
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882858+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882860+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882862+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882864+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 
'../models/Project.js'
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882865+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882867+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load 
(module.js:468:25)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882868+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require 
(module.js:587:17)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882870+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require 
(internal/module.js:11:18)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882872+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> 
(/app/controllers/projectController.js:5:17)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882873+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile 
(module.js:643:30)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882875+00:00 app[web.1]:     at 
Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882878+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad 
(module.js:499:12)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882876+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load 
(module.js:556:32)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.882879+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load 
(module.js:491:3)
2018-03-14T01:32:58.959966+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2018-03-14T01:32:58.949469+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: is `models/Project.js` outside the directory that is being uploaded to Heroku?

Comment: nope im uploading the entire repo. The models folder is in the root dir.

Comment: Then why can't it find `Project.js`? That's a question that's going to be hard to answer without a lot more information, such as your directory structure.

Comment: https://github.com/kyl3thegreat/projects here's a link to the repo